# How byte addressing works?

Tags: memory, byte, memory-address, cpu-architecture

I am new to computer architecture. So correct me if I am wrong.

If a memory module consists of 8 memory chips and if each chip stores 4bits per address then by applying an address to the address pin of the module I can get (8 x 4=) 32 bit from that address in the module. But byte addressing tells that every byte has an address. But here I am accessing 32bits using an address. So how is it possible?

I think if each chip stores 1bit per address then by applying an address to the module I can access 8bit or one byte.

Comment: Which real-word chip are you talking about?

Comment: You should read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).  It was written mainly to explain why it's important to care about cache when coding, but it starts with a background on how memory is arranged and connected to CPUs, down to the level of DDR DIMMs and the signalling mechanism for sending addresses to DIMMs and then writing or reading data on the same bus.  It has a more complete answer to this question than I'm prepared to paraphrase and type.  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some other good links for x86.

Comment: @Michael I thought he was talking about DIMMs. So my answer ignored the cache which probably be the most practical solution.

Comment: I think my question refers to this point how byte addressing is implemented in 32 bit or 64 bit DIMM?

Comment: @Kaustav: In DDR SDRAM, it's not.  Reads and writes always happen in bursts.  I think the burst size is 64B, matching the cache line size of modern x86 CPUs.  Writing a byte happens in cache, marking the whole cache-line as dirty.  AFAICT, a single-byte write to a memory that's marked as marked as uncacheable must generate a read-modify-write within the memory controller, since [there is no non-burst read or write command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#Commands).

Answer (score 0):

You say each chip stores 4bits per address and you have 8 on the same address bus. It is the address bus that is the limiting factor. The address bus must have 32 lines for each byte in a 32 bit architecture to be addressable. If you have 8 chips each producing 4 bits in response to the same address, then you have 32bits per address. The advantage of such an arrangement would be the address bus lines could be reduced by 2 without decreasing the addressable range (only the resolution).

You are correct in thinking that each chip would need to produce 1 bit per address to allow byte addressing.

That's the theory, in practice I would suspect a solution could be architected where the 4 bits could be time division multiplexed making each individually accessible.

I have heard for a long time not to address less than 32 bits at a time, as that may be the smallest unit addressable. Certainly it would make sense when 2Gb-4Gb was the physical limit of 32 bit byte  addressing.

Comment: So how can every byte from that 32bit or 4byte can be addressed separately in byte addressing scheme?

Comment: Bit masking, and/or bit shifting. If you need bits, there are typically language specific boolean containers. Point is this is not necessarily uncommon on embedded systems, although not standard 32 bit architecture. What is the chip?

Comment: My question is not any language specific. It's about the organisation. If the addresses inside the individual chips contain more than 1 bit then an address refers to more than a byte. So how byte addressing is applied here?

Comment: As we say, you are addressing 32bits so that must be broken down somewhere, either by TDM or bit masks and shifts.

Comment: I am new to computer architecture. So may be I am wrong. Is TDM or bit masking and shifting gives separate address to those each bytes or it just enable us to access those separate bytes but using the same address?

Comment: Can do, but if you had a specific chip in mind then byte addressing is probably at the register or cache level once a whole 32 bits has been read in.